# How to generate iPA file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I want to generate my project's iPA file to test on device. I searched related to generating iPA file and it says in your Xcode select Product option, in which you could select Archive option.

But i found archive option blur and i am not able to select it. Why it is blur?[image]

Comment: Make sure you are not choosing the Simulator.you need to select the ios device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Device in-place of Simulator and then make Archive .

[image]

Comment: welcome @Nisha. please mark as right if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQB3K.png you need to select the 'Generic Ios device' and the go for product -> Archive

Answer (score 0):

select device as Generic IOS Device in devices tab

Goto Project -> Archive -> building of your project start after this organiser window will open 
in organiser window there is an option "Export" click on that and save your IPA on to your location